# Developer account - DocuSign Envelopes - Custom object

Tags: docusignapi

Hi I'm integrating from Developer account to my sandbox salesforce via REST API. The document signing API is working, but how do I associate the envelop to a salesforce record so that it shows up on the DocuSign Envelopes related list? It works if I send the document via a custom button on the custom object in the UI. Is it possible to do so via API calls?

Comment: StackOverflow is a forum used to get help with Code. For generic how-to specific questions I advise using that platforms specific forums (https://community.docusign.com/ for DocuSign).

Answer (score 0):

I believe the creation of the DocuSign Envelopes records are controlled by the DocuSign for Salesforce managed package. That would explain why it works when utilizing your custom button, but not your API integration.

Out of the box, "DocuSign Envelope Statuses" are generated regardless of where it is sent from. As long as you pass the Salesforce record ID within a DocuSign Envelope Custom Field within your request, you could configure Connect to relate the envelope to a specific Salesforce record.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did both things.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did both things in Apex. But it's not working. This is the REST API request: "customFields" : {
    "textCustomFields" : [ {
      "name" : "Terms_and_Conditions__c",
      "show" : "true",
      "required" : "true",
      "value" : "a1mc0000000c9EEAAY",
      "customFieldType" : "text"
    } ]
  }
In salesforce sandbox, on object dsfs__DocuSign_Status__c, there is a look up to the custom object Terms_and_Conditions__c. In the developer demo connect, for dsfs__DocuSign_Status__c, update field is Terms_and_Conditions__c, docusign field is envelop external source id.

Comment: However, with this set up, the envelop sent by the API does not show under DocuSign Status related list on the Terms_and_Conditions__c custom object record a1mc0000000c9EEAAY.